# How to avoid program to be detected as a trojan?

Tags: c++, windows-defender

I made a small program to detect mouse moving from a screen to another on multiscreen configuration and it is detected as a trojan on windows 10 by windows defender. On my pc it is not detected (windows 7 pro 64) by windows defender nor my antivirus.
I'm using just a few functions:

```
GetCursorPos(&P);

...

HWND hwnd = WindowFromPoint(P);
            HWND hparent = GetParent(hwnd);
            while (hparent)
            {
                hwnd = hparent;
                hparent = GetParent(hwnd);
            }
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
```

Is there something in that code that can be suspicious ?

Thanks

Comment: Report it to MS as a false positive so they can improve their detection?

Comment: I agree, report it. But tracking cursor position and figuring out what window the cursor belongs to is potentially suspicious activity (not saying your code as such is, but this would be the type of thing that some spyware does, to try to figure out when you are entering your password to your bank, or similar)

Comment: You can try feeding your program to virustotal and see if it really is windows-defender being oversensitive or if it is in fact suspicious enough.

Comment: I reported it to microsoft... on virustotal it is not detected by any antivirus, so it seems cool, don't know the problem with the user reported me the issue.